# Josephus Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, josephus

I was reading the algorithm for the [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

I came across the following algorithm :

```
int josephusIteration(int n,int k) {
    int a=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        a=(a+k-1)%i+1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

I couldn't understand its logic. Suppose n=5 and k=2.

```
i=1, a=1
i=2, a=1
i=3, a=3
i=4, a=1
i=5, a=3
```

Can anybody explain this by giving an example?

Comment: Do you have a problem in understanding the Josephus problem in general or do you specifically want to understand this particular algorithm. I ask because it has a recursive solution easier to understand.

Comment: I have a problem in understanding the problem itself. I mean why is it continuosly taking %i? What does a stand for every iteration?

Comment: i represents the number of people alive as you compute backwards from the point where only one is left to the original total.  The key to a non recursive solution is to work backwards through the executions.  The modulo i is because we have circle at each step and count k positions around the circle.  The a represents the position within the circle of the person who would survive.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Read my answer below to understand the recursive solution of Josephus problem. Let me know if you don't understand it fully.

Answer (score 6):

If `n = 5` and `k = 2`, then the safe position is `3`. Firstly, the person at position 2 is killed, then person at position 4 is killed, then person at position 1 is killed. Finally, the person at position 5 is killed. So the person at position 3 survives.

I have read your code but I would like to suggest a recursive solution below which is easier to understand.

```
// this function returns the position of the person alive
int josephus(int n, int k)
{
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    /* The position returned by josephus(n - 1, k) is adjusted because the
       recursive call josephus(n - 1, k) considers the original position 
       k%n + 1 as position 1 */
    return (josephus(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1;
}
```

After the first person (kth from begining) is killed, n-1 persons are left. So we call `josephus(n – 1, k)` to get the position with n-1 persons.

But the position returned by `josephus(n – 1, k)` will consider it again from the position 1. So we add `k-1` to it and take its modulus with `n` as there are `n` elements and add 1 to make the position `1-indexed` rather than `0-indexed`.

Reference: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/josephus-problem-set-1-a-on-solution/

Comment: Copy from geeksforgeeks.http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/josephus-problem-set-1-a-on-solution/

Comment: @BlackBird Added reference. I have added to the explanation mentioned at the website.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal You need to first understand why we add `k-1` to the previous value. Then `%i` is done to make sure the value returned is in range [1, i].

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at how the formula `a = (a + k - 1) % i + 1;` is derived. We can do that by starting with the recursive call in [unrealsoul007's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31657630/1288).

```
return (josephus(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1;
```

That can be rewritten as:

```
j = josephus(n - 1, k);
return (j + k-1) % n + 1;
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
j = josephus(n - 1, k);
pos = (j + k-1) % n + 1;
return pos;
```

The second line can now be rewritten to the original formula we were trying to derive, except in this case we have `% n`, but in the original we had `% i`. This is because as we make recursive calls `n` is decreasing, but as those recursive calls *return* `n` is increasing again (like `i` in the loop version).

The reason we need to do the `%` operation is because when we get to the end of the circle, we need to start over back at the beginning. The reason we add 1 is because we don't want to return the position of the person just eliminated. We want to return the position of the *next* person, where we start counting again in the next iteration. When `n-1` people have been eliminated, that position is the last person remaining, so it's the final return value.